# Attached Events

Tags: xaml, c++-cx

I would like to attach a click event to my container, but the c++/cx way eludes me.  Both XAML and programmatic approaches have left me frustrated.  How can I attach events in general? (and specifically the Click event of a Button?)  Neither of the following ways have worked for me:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Button.Click="stackPanel_Click">
    <Button>Button #1</Button>
    <Button>Button #2</Button>    
</StackPanel>
```

This just gives the error, "Unknown attachable member 'Button.Click' on element 'StackPanel'. Yet, this is how it's done in WPF.  And programmatically:

```
stackPanel->AddHandler(
  Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Button::Click,
  ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventHandler(this, stackPanel_Click),
  false);
```

This gives "Error: a non static member reference must be relative to a specific object"-- which is referring to the first parameter of AddHandler.

I mostly understand the errors given, but still have no clue how to accomplish what I would like.  Search engines give no help, and Microsofts documentation hasn't been enlightening either.

Comment: And that's why I need to attach the event to it. When the Button(s) Click event fires it will bubble up to the StackPanel--This code works fine in C# WPF, but not with a UWP app in c++/cx.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought and a little more research I've discovered the solutions.

XAML

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" UIElement.Tapped="stackPanel_Tapped">
  <Button>Button #1</Button>
  <Button>Button #2</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

In Code

```
// For in-code-only setup, consider this constructor and
// OnLoaded code.
MyPage::MyPage() {
  InitializeComponent();

  Loaded += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventHandler(this, &MyPage::OnLoaded);
}

void MyPage::OnLoaded(Platform::Object^ sender, RoutedEventArgs^ e) {
  stackPanel->AddHandler(
    UIElement::TappedEvent,
    ref new TappedEventHandler(this, &MyPage::stackPanel_Tapped),
    false);
}

// If you setup the event handling in XAML this is the only code you'll need.
void MyPage::stackPanel_Tapped(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::TappedRoutedEventArgs^ e) {
  // Event handling code . . .
}
```

The reason the first example code didn't work was that there doesn't seem to be any reference to a RoutedEvent object for click, which would be named ClickEvent by convention.  Despite this, the documentation still says Button::Click is a routed event. The platform seems to favor a higher level of abstraction and instead defines a routed event called Tapped.  UWP applications can run on many different devices after all, not all of which have a mouse or cursor.  Both events, click and tapped, can be used, but only tapped can be used as an attached event--it's the only one we have access to the RoutedEvent object of the routed event it seems.

The second notable and very related point is with the in-code implementation. You pass in the RoutedEvent object, named TappedEvent, and not the event named Tapped.  I only mention it because the XAML code might trick you into just typing in Tapped instead of TappedEvent, which could leave you scratching your head for a bit, even while you're looking at the AddHandler function prototype in intellisense.

Comment: `Click` events in UWP XAML don't route through the tree. You could of course just add a `Click` handler to the buttons themselves. Also, you should unhook the `Loaded` event as soon as it is raised, because it might get raised again in the future and you'll have two `Tapped` handlers.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Thanks for pointing a potential problem with the loaded event.  As far as I understand it when navigating away from a page, the page object is serialized.  Then if you happen to navigate 'back' to the page another instance is created and the object is "rehydrated".  Is this the circumstance you were thinking of? Or is there another situation where Loaded is called, but the original object not destroyed?  That part of the code modeled the code from Microsoft's web site, so I included it.  (On the UWP Pages don't seem to have a property KeepAlive to do just that.)

Comment: Navigation can recycle pages depending on various circumstances. Also in general you could get another Loaded event if the page (or any of its parents) are removed and re-added to the tree, eg as part of some transitions or responsive design.